# facebook graph api explorer return values only for life time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am searching for likes given to videos in facebook page.....But I am returned with lifetime values instead of specific date value.

I am using C#.net windows application

**For Example**:
The below link we used to get the values

https://graph.facebook.com/2.4/pageID_VideoID/insights/period=day
returns lifetime value instead of day values.

Please help me to find out solution......

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the endpoint like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/2.4/{post_id}/insights?period=day
```

where `{post_id}` is the post's unique id.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/insights#modifiers

Comment: Hi Tobi, I am getting the LIFETIME value for the link provided above.

My issue is...... For the periods day/week/days_28, the result values are same....which it shouldn't be like that. 

For day the views to video different from week&days_28 but for every period the results shows the same.

Please help me out..........

Comment: Use the `?` instead of `/` before the `period` parameter! Did you change that?